# Regex for value.contains() in Google Refine

Tags: regex, google-refine

I have a column of strings, and I want to use a regex to find commas **or** pipes in every cell, and then make an action. I tried this, but it doesn't work (*no syntax error*, just doesn't match neither commas nor pipes).

```
if(value.contains(/(,|\|)/), ...
```

The funny thing is that the same regex works with the same data in SublimeText. (Yes, I can work it there and then reimport, but I would like to understand what's the difference or what is my mistake).

I'm using Google Refine 2.5.

Comment: Are you sure `value.contains` can accept a regex? Try `if(value.match(/.*[,|].*/)`

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but I tried both value.match and value.contains with your regex (and mine), and the behaviour is the same. I'm starting to think that maybe the issue is escaping the pipe: `/\|/`should find the pipe, but doesn't work.

Comment: Acc. to the [GREL cheatsheet](http://arcadiafalcone.net/GoogleRefineCheatSheets.pdf) `value.contains` supports regex and that escaping should work. Maybe the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Well, now it seems that is in fact the regex that breaks everything. If I put "string" everything works, if I use regex doesn't.

Comment: Well, it seems that `match` only returns capture groups. Try `if(value.match(/.*([,|]).*/) != null)`  or `if (value.partition(/.*[,|].*/) != null)` or something like that. See [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openrefine-dev/sdXQKTpbY0k).

Comment: Thanks, the first one works.

Comment: I don't think that GREL cheatsheet is correct. Current documentation including the Wiki https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions and the help information within the application says that 'contains' accepts a string fragment, but does not mention regex

Comment: Yes. From what I understand, contains() doesn't support regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `value.match` should return captured texts, you need to define a regex with a capture group and check if the result is not null.

Also, pay attention to the regex itself: the string should be matched [*in its entirety*](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#matchstring-s-regexp-p):

> Attempts to match the string s in its entirety against the regex pattern p and returns an array of capture groups.

So, add `.*` before and after the pattern you are looking *inside* a larger string:

```
if(value.match(/.*([,|]).*/) != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of if and isNonBlank like:

```
if(isNonBlank(value.match(/your regex/), ...
```